# Is there a concept class in ExtJs framework?

Tags: javascript, class, extjs

According to my knowledge in javascript,there are objects and we can create objects for a function or we can create objects using literal notation..i never seen the concept of class in javascript.recently i have started to learn EXTJS(a javascript library)..in EXTJS people are saying like predefined classes(eg.EXt,Panel etc.) are there and even in api docs they are writing as class..it does not make sense to me..my questions are

1.why **extjs** people are using the word **"CLASS"**?

2.if class concept is there in extjs what way i have to think it?

3.is there a concept "CLASS" in js(i think no)?

Answer (score 2):

Everything in JavaScript acts like an object (*JavaScript is a prototype-based, object-oriented scripting language*) with the only two exceptions being `null` and `undefined`. Even functions are objects (Actually, this is why JavaScript is said to have [**first-class-functions**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-class_function))

For ExtJS, "class" is a *virtual* concept: that is a conceptual extension created by the authors of the framework (relying on JavaScript way to declare classes)

Comment: thanks dmarucco.now it makes sense to me why extjs people are using the term "class'.

Answer (score 0):

Try reading this..

http://www.phpied.com/3-ways-to-define-a-javascript-class/

Comment: i have already read that one.According to that we should treat in javascript function as class.so in extjs the people are talking class wrt to function?

Answer (score 0):

No, there are no classes in Javascript, but it supports some object oriented principles. You can make a function that you can use as constructor for an object:

```
function Point(x, y) {
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
}
```

By using the `new` keyword, the function will be used as a constructor:

```
var p = new Point(4, 5);
```

Using the `prototype` keyword you can add methods to the objects that are created with a specific function, which is similar to putting methods in a class.

Although this is actually not a class as far as the language is concerned, it walks and talks like a class, at least in some aspects. It's useful to use the term class when describing how it's intended to be used, even if it's actually not a class.

Comment: **"It's useful to use the term class when describing how it's intended to be used, even if it's actually not a class."**  nice sentence